# Angular2: ViewChild Referencing in constructor of class or in class body?

Tags: angular

What is best practice and where is the difference between:

```
export class suchPage {
    @ViewChild(SuchDirective) suchDirective:SuchDirective;
}
```

and

```
export class suchPage {
    @ViewChild(SuchDirective);


    constructor(
        private suchDirective:SuchDirective
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation references the first method. I'm guessing it's the best practice:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

Answer (score 3):

Second method won't work because `ViewChild` injected element is only available after the view init (`ngAfterViewInit`).